# elasticsearch can't hanlde space after add synonym analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

I created an index called `my_index` by this command

```
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "synonym": {
                    "type": "synonym",
                    "lenient": "true",
                    "synonyms": [
                        ...
                        ...
                        ...
                    ]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "synonym": {
                    "filter": [
                        "uppercase",
                        "synonym"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "items": {
            "properties": {
                "country": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "information": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": "synonym"
                },
                "person": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

inside `information`, I had a data that looks like this `100 /INDIA/2022` (pay attention to the space after 100). If i search for `100/INDIA/2022` (no space after 100), elasticsearch will return nothing. If I create new index with no analyzer, `100/INDIA/2022` will return the expected result. Can someone help me for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`synonym` analyzer defined in your index settings, includes tokenizing the text on whitespace. So, on analyzing the text `100 /INDIA/2022`

```
GET 71595890/_analyze
{
  "text": "100 /INDIA/2022",
  "analyzer": "synonym"
}
```

Following tokens are produced

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "100",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 3,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "/INDIA/2022",
      "start_offset" : 4,
      "end_offset" : 15,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Since you have not explicitly defined any `search_analyzer` then by default index analyzer (which is the analyzer you have defined in your index mapping) is the same as the search analyzer.

So, when you are searching for `100/INDIA/2022`, the text gets tokenized into

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "100/INDIA/2022",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 14,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

**There is no matching token produced (when compared to `100` and `/INDIA/2022`), therefore no documents will match.**

---

In the second case when you have created a new index with no analyzer, then by default standard analyzer is taken.

In the case of [`standard` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) following tokens are produced

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "100",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 3,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "india",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 10,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "2022",
      "start_offset" : 11,
      "end_offset" : 15,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 2
    }
  ]
}
```

The tokens made with `100 /INDIA/2022` and `100/INDIA/2022` with standard analyzer are same as shown above.

Comment: Okay, so i see update the tokenizer into `standard` solved the problem. Thank you